# RXJS on multiple dependent API calls

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to combine multiple API calls into a single observable using RXJS, anyone has any suggestions?

- getUser() //returns single user
- getEmployeeList() //returns array of Employees
- getVisitsByEmployeeId(employeeId) //Using a single employee id, returns array of Visits
- getVisitDetails(visistId) //iterate over visits & return visit details

```
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit {
  displayData: any;

  constructor(private dummyService: DummyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.myBigAssObserveable().subscribe(
      response => this.displayData = response;
    );
  }

  myBigAssObserveable() {
    
  }


getEmployeeDetails() {
    forkJoin(
        {user:this.dummyService.getLoggerInUser(),
         employees: this.employeeService.getEmployees()})
    .subscribe(({user, employees}) => 
        return employees.find(i => i.find(i.employeeId == user.id))
}

  getVisitDetails() {
    return this.visitService
    .getVisitsById(employeeId)
    .pipe(
      flatMap((response) => 
      this.dummyService.getVisitDetails(response.visitId)));
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on how the observables are related. Are they completely unrelated (i.e fetch all info parallely) or do they depend on one another (i.e the subsequent request needs to wait till the previous request completes)?

Comment: RxJS comes with a lot of tools to help you structure asynchronous calls. There is no magic spell that combines observables for you though. In this regard, they're like regular functions. For example: there are many ways to 'combine' string concatenation and addition, but there's no general **way** that makes sense. Do you want ("Hello", 8, 5) = "Hello13" or ("Hello", 8, 5) = "Hello Thirteen" both  answers 'combine' string concatenation and addition.

Comment: Thank @MichaelD for your response. I suppose it would make more sense if the calls are dependent on each other. I need the User & Employees to get the employeeID, which is required to get visits for the employee, which in turn is required to get visit details to display on screen. What do you think is the best option?

Comment: Please share the shape of the data (interfaces) that each api call returns.

Comment: Also, please clarify on what you mean by "combine".  What is your desired output shape?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your object destruction got some issue. Could you please update your getEmployeeDetails() module as follows.

```
getEmployeeDetails() {
    forkJoin(
        {user:this.dummyService.getLoggerInUser(),
         employees: this.employeeService.getEmployees()})
    .subscribe(({user, employees}) => 
        return employees.find(i => i.find(i.employeeId == user.id))
}
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you.